# Calcular numeros que no caben en un long -Java

Tags: java, matemáticas

Estoy haciendo por curiosidad el tipico problema del trigo en el tablero de ajedrez el cual consiste en poner una semilla de trigo en la primera casilla, el doble en la segunda, el doble en la tercera y asi hasta la 64.

EL problema es que el resultado final no cabe nisiquiera en una variable Long
Como solucionarian este problema?

Este es mi codigo

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    long trigo=1;
    for(int i=0;i<64;i++){
        trigo=trigo*2;
        System.out.println("casilla "+(i+1)+":"+trigo+" Trigos");
        }
}
```

y mi output es este

```
casilla 1:2 Trigos
casilla 2:4 Trigos
casilla 3:8 Trigos
casilla 4:16 Trigos
casilla 5:32 Trigos
.
.
.
casilla 35:34359738368 Trigos
casilla 36:68719476736 Trigos
casilla 47:140737488355328 Trigos
casilla 48:281474976710656 Trigos
casilla 49:562949953421312 Trigos
.
.
.
casilla 62:4611686018427387904 Trigos
```

y aqui se daña

```
casilla 63:-9223372036854775808 Trigos
casilla 64:0 Trigos
```

Comment: Has intentado utilizar los `biginteger`?

Comment: @matahombres es la opción correcta y además no veo duplicados claros. Te animo a responder :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Viendo que @matahombres no responde te lo pongo yo: para números más grandes que lo que cabe en `long` puedes usar [`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigInteger.html), en concreto el método [`BigInteger.multiply`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigInteger.html#multiply(java.math.BigInteger)).

Ten en cuenta que `multiply` requiere otro `BigInteger` que en tu caso valdrá 2:

```
BigInteger trigo = BigInteger.ONE; // BigInteger tiene valores ya definidos para 1, 2 y 10

for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
    trigo = trigo.multiply(BigInteger.TWO);
    System.out.println("casilla "+(i+1)+":"+trigo+" Trigos");
}
```

Comment: Efectivamente me funciono, gracias, lo unico es que esta linea `trigo = trigo.multiply(BigInteger.TWO);` me daba el error de "BigInteger(long) has private access in BigInteger" y la cambie por `trigo = trigo.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(2));`